# How send money to paypal account from console app?

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I use [PayPal-NET-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) for interact with PayPal system (sanbox). I have next code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
            var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
            var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

            var payment = Payment.Create(apiContext, new Payment
            {
                intent = "order",
                payer = new Payer
                {
                    payment_method = "paypal"
                },
                transactions = new List<Transaction>
                {
                    new Transaction
                    {
                        description = "Transaction description.",
                        invoice_number = "002",
                        amount = new Amount
                        {
                            currency = "USD",
                            total = "15.00",
                        },
                        payee = new Payee
                        {
                            email = "test1@gmail.com"
                        }
                    }
                },
                redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls
                {
                    return_url = "site for redirect", // in my code there is normal url
                    cancel_url = "site for redirect""
                }
            });

            var approval = payment.GetTokenFromApprovalUrl();

            var url = payment.GetApprovalUrl();


            payment.token = approval;

            var response = payment.Execute(apiContext, new PaymentExecution {payer_id = "C598R54Q6P39G" });
        }
        catch (PaymentsException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Response);
        }
    }
```

After executing this code i receive bad request error from PayPal ("Payer has not approved payment"). If go to link in url in debug, i get to PayPal confirm page, and after push continue button, payment executing withoue exceptions (but funds still same, money is not sending). How i can send money to other paypal wallet without redirect to PayPal aproving page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using payout (as i uderstand, payments use for client to merchant transfer).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Authenticate with PayPal
            var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
            var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
            var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

            var payout = Payout.Create(apiContext, new Payout
            {
                sender_batch_header = new PayoutSenderBatchHeader
                {
                    email_subject = "Hello payout",
                    sender_batch_id = "ilab_Payout002",
                    recipient_type = PayoutRecipientType.EMAIL
                },
                items = new List<PayoutItem>
                {
                    new PayoutItem
                    {
                        amount = new Currency
                        {
                            currency = "USD",
                            value = "17.5"
                        },
                        note = "Exchange is done!",
                        receiver = "ilab-test1@gmail.com",
                        recipient_type = PayoutRecipientType.EMAIL,
                        sender_item_id = "121341"
                    }
                },
            });
        }
        catch (PaymentsException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Response);
        }
    }
}
```